# Let's Encypt for Laravel Application with Nginx on LEMP Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt

First time for everything here (DigitalOcean, Laravel, Github, etc). Sorry in advance for my ignorance.

I have successfully been able to deploy the [Marketplacekit](https://github.com/marketplacekit/marketplacekit) app on my Ubuntu 16.04 LEMP droplet. Everything was working as it should prior to trying to install an SSL.

I have been using a combination of these great tutorials from DigitalOcean.

[(1) How To Deploy a Laravel Application with Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)
[(2) How To Install Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP (LEMP stack) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04)

I am currently trying to install Let's Encypt SSL certificates across my domain (Step 6 of tutorial (1)).

Originally after following step 6 I got these errors:

```
include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
```

Another user had the same errors as the files did not exist using the tutorial method. So I tried to manually create the files using [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028071/unable-to-set-https-using-letsencrypt-in-nginx-server) they suggested.

It seems that the SSL is working properly, but **now I am getting 404 Not Found error.**

Here is my enabled config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com
```

--

```
server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            # SSL configuration
            #
            # listen 443 ssl default_server;
            # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
            #
            # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
            # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
            #
            # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
            # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
            #
            # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
            # Don't use them in a production server!
            #
            # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

            root /var/www/html/marketplacekit/public;

            # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name example.com www.example.com;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


            location / {
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }


            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny all;
            }



            # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
            #
            #location ~ \.php$ {
            #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            #
            #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            #       # With php7.0-fpm:
            #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            #}

            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one
            #
            #location ~ /\.ht {
            #       deny all;
            #}
    }


    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

            include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
            include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

            root /var/www/html/quickstart/public;

            index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name example.com www.example.com;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            }

            location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny all;
            }

            location ~ /.well-known {
                    allow all;
            }
    }
```

Comment: What tutorial are you following to install Let'ts Encrypt? This was the one I followed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 You could also review this one: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-asegurar-nginx-con-let-s-encrypt-en-ubuntu-18-04-es

Comment: I did steps 1-3 on the one you used. Then jumped to step 6 in the (1) tutorial I linked.
`sudo certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html/marketplacekit/public -d example.com -d www.example.com`

Comment: did you changed `-d example.com -d www.example.com` for your domain right?

Comment: Yes, the site was secured when I went to it, but it was giving 404. So it seems like the SSL was working, just not the right config.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work.

1. Remove /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-example.com.conf
2. Remove /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf
3. Remove /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem

Delete and recreate nginx enabled config file and install SSL as per this tutorial.

[Follow this tutorial instead](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-let-s-encrypt-with-nginx-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Config file looks like this, last part was created automatically on install of the certs.

```
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/marketplacekit/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;


    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }



    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Let's encrypt is like a godfather for small startup and developers by providing the free SSL. If you are using nginx in the Ubuntu then you do not need to do anything by yourself. just install the certbot for the let's encrypt and it will do the required configuration by itself in the site-enabled file. If you are still facing issue then I will recommend you to read a tutorial on how to [install let's encrypt on nginx](https://codesquery.com/install-lets-encrypt-to-secure-nginx-web-server/) for laraval